# Is it possible to use Map reduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I have several hundred of millions rows in database as input data.
   Every 10000 rows processing tooks approximately 15 minutes cause external API requests are involved.

I am going to divide it into data spots and process with hundred Amazon AWS EC2 instances. Every process launched on EC2 instance will also save output in database.

Is it possible to organize this multiagent task as map reduce claster using Cloud services?

Comment: "several hundred rows"? That's next to nothing for a decent database... unless each row is a multi-gigabyte blob field, of course.

Comment: I really don';t understand why you would need 100 instance dedicated to Map Reduce in order to process several hundred rows.  What is in these rows and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarcB Sorry for misprinting, several hundred of millions rows, of course

Comment: @MikeBrant Sorry for misprinting, several hundred of millions rows, of course

Comment: Every 10000 rows processing tooks approximately 15 minutes cause external API requests are involved.